# Correct and crossplatform way to use UTF-8 in C++ streams

Tags: c++, utf-8, stl, iostream

As i understood from [this answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17189385/1794089), there is a [still unfixed bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/431244/std-ostream-fails-to-write-utf-8-encoded-string-to-console) in the Visual C++ STL implementation.
So, there is no possibility to just write `std::cout << raw_utf8_string << std::endl` and enjoy the nice UTF-8 chars under Windows ;(

NOTE: My test program lives [here](https://gist.github.com/eraxillan/a12770138da05f5bee34).

But maybe there is an quite simple-to-understand workaround to handle this?
My thoghts: make a wrapper class like `cout_ex`, which will use Windows API `WriteConsoleA`
for console output.
In its constructor do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15845530/1794089):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
if (IsValidCodePage (CP_UTF8))
{
    if (!SetConsoleCP (CP_UTF8))
        std::cout << "Could not set console input code page to UTF-8" << std::endl;
    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP (CP_UTF8))
        std::cout << "Could not set console output code page to UTF-8" << std::endl;
}
else
    std::cout << "UTF-8 code page is not supported in your system" <<   std::endl;
#endif
```

And in output method do this:

```
char const raw_utf8_text[] = "Blåbærsyltetøy! кошка!";

DWORD raw_written = 0;
WriteConsoleA (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), raw_utf8_text, std::strlen (raw_utf8_text), &raw_written, NULL);
```

And don't forget to use the undocumented Visual C++ pragma at the very beginning of src:

```
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")
```

But maybe one have a more clear solution :) Even with using some external libs like Poco/Boost/etc.

I try to read those articles [1](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/unicode-part-1-windows-console-io-approaches/), [2](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/), but i found this way is too complicated.
P.S. Overrided stream class also should set console font to the Unicode one.
P.P.S. Software versions: Windows 8 x64 + Visual C++ 2013 Express.

Comment: I didn't check in depth `SetConsoleCP`, but the general mantra is that on Windows UTF-8 is not a supported CP (`CP_UTF8` being there mostly for `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`). The typical way you work in UTF-8 on Windows is to convert to `WCHAR` at API boundaries.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck setting the console CP to CP_UNICODE and then converting your UTF-8 to UTF-16 manually (remember CP_UNICODE==UTF-16).

Comment: @MatteoItalia So under Windows i can only convert to UTF-16 and use std::wcout for output?

Comment: @rodrigo I will check this. However, Unicode != UTF-16 :) Why Microsoft think so, i don't understand...

Comment: @Axilles: I know that, that's why I said `CP_UNICODE`, not _Unicode_. And even weirder is why they think ANSI equals... something useful.

Comment: @rodrigo Hm, under `CP_UNICODE` you mean the `1200` code page? but documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx) what it is available only to managed applications! But i use unmanaged C++.

Comment: @rodrigo I ask because Visual C++ don't know about `CP_UNICODE` constant (windows.h is included).
Also, `assert (IsValidCodePage (1200))` is raised, i.e. it is invalid.

Comment: @Axilles: I stand corrected! There are no such `CP_UNICODE`. But maybe you can use `WriteConsoleW()` directly to bypass the codepage stuff.

Comment: [Stl and utf-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018384/stl-and-utf-8-file-input-output-how-to-do-it/4025951)

Comment: @Axilles, are wide characters for internal use a no-go for you in this question's scope?

Comment: @rodrigo Yep, `WriteConsoleW` works correctly (however it prints a square at the end of string). But std::wcout don't...

Comment: @Basilevs Yes, i'm interesting in using pure UTF-8 strings. Without any conversion. If it possible even with black magic :)

Answer (score 1):

You should imbue a proper codecvt_facet within your output stream.

```
std::locale loc;
string encoding=getOutputEncoding(); // 
loc=std::locale(loc, createCodecvt(encoding));
cout.imbue(loc);
cout.rdbuf().imbue(loc);
```

[Complete code here](https://sourceforge.net/p/fakedetector/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/fakebase/src/locale_init.cpp#l212)

This facet should convert internal encoding to external one. Due to [some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688965/stdcodecvtdo-in-method-overloading-vs-the-rest-of-base-methods/22694412#22694412) in STL implementation this might be impossible to do if internal storage format is in one-byte or multibyte encoding. There is a workaround for that - to use filestreambuf instead of default output buffer.

You might have to implement your own codecvt_facet or use my [iconv wrapper](https://sourceforge.net/p/fakedetector/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/fakebase/src/codecvt_iconv.h).

Overall I still recommend to use wide characters for internal processing. This way you might even avoid any extra conversions (besides system default ones).

Comment: So, where is no way to output UTF-8 *without* conversion? Any hack, workaround - whatever. This is the main goal of the question

Comment: Of course there is. [First question you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660492/utf-8-output-on-windows-xp-console) mentions that fputs method works just fine. IMHO you may use fstreambuf (with conversions settings disabled in imbued locale) on stdout. You will get garbage on misconfigured console, though.

Comment: I checked `fputs` - it work correctly. Thanks!
 So, only the Microsoft STL streams implementation has problems with UTF-8. Where can i read more about it reason? for the current moment it's hard to understand for me :(

Comment: But you linked that question yourself! There is an exhaustive explanation. Just follow links. Specifically http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/431244/std-ostream-fails-to-write-utf-8-encoded-string-to-console

Comment: Hm, looks like i'm too tired today :D Sorry. I need to rest and slowly read and to digest what i read. So much information - and meanwhile in Linux things are just working.